# Send back not empty xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

Why **sendResponse({ helloWorld: sendto })** sending back empty string and not that **this.responseText** is assigned to sendto variable? How to manage my code properly to achieve sending back this.responseText and not the empty string?

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(

        function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
            **var sendto = 'empty';**
            var ccc = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ccc.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    console.log(this.responseText)
                    **sendto = this.responseText;**




                }
            }
            ccc.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:3000/" + request.greeting)
            ccc.send();

            **sendResponse({ helloWorld: sendto });**

        });
```

Comment: Add `return true;` at the end of the listener function in order to provide an asynchronous response.

Comment: it wont work ...

Comment: Try with the posted answer

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `return true;` to the listener function in order to use `sendResponse` asynchronously. For example:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(

    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        var ccc = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ccc.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                console.log(this.responseText)
                sendResponse({helloWorld: this.responseText});
            }
        };

        ccc.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:3000/" + request.greeting)
        ccc.send();

        return true;  // in order to use sendResponse asynchronously

    });
```